# Android studio got an error when updated to the latest version

Tags: android, android-studio, gradle

I updated android studio to latest version and got this error

[build.gradle](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2yjAb.png)

**Error message**

```
Plugin [id: 'com.android.application', version: '7.1.2', apply: false] was not found in any of the following sources:

* Try:
Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.

* Exception is:
org.gradle.api.plugins.UnknownPluginException: Plugin [id: 'com.android.application', version: '7.1.2', apply: false] was not found in any of the following sources:

- Gradle Core Plugins (plugin is not in 'org.gradle' namespace)
- Plugin Repositories (could not resolve plugin artifact 'com.android.application:com.android.application.gradle.plugin:7.1.2')
  Searched in the following repositories:
    Gradle Central Plugin Repository
    Google
    MavenRepo
..........
```

Answer (score 1):

I have a same problem. And I have solved that.

```
buildscript {
    ext {
        kotlin_version = '1.5.30'
        compose_version = '1.0.5'
    }
    repositories {
        google()
        mavenCentral()
        gradlePluginPortal()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath "com.android.tools.build:gradle:7.1.2"
        classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:$kotlin_version"
    }
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

Add this code. It will work

Comment: not work at all